# GraphViz Install Fail

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, pear, graphviz

I am trying to install graphviz on an ubuntu server but am getting the following error..

> sudo pear install Image_GraphViz
>
> downloading Image_GraphViz-1.3.0.tgz ...
>
> Starting to download Image_GraphViz-1.3.0.tgz (16,706 bytes)
>   ......done: 16,706 bytes
>
> could not extract the package.xml file from "/build/buildd/php5-5.5.9+dfsg/pear-build-download/Image_GraphViz-1.3.0.tgz"
>
> Download of "pear/Image_GraphViz" succeeded, but it is not a valid package archive
>
> Error: cannot download "pear/Image_GraphViz"
>
> Download failed
>
> install failed

Any advice? Some info below in case it matters...

---

```
PEAR Version: 1.9.4
PHP Version: 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.9
Zend Engine Version: 2.5.0
Running on: Linux xServer 3.16.0-34-generic #47~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Apr 10 17:49:51 UTC 2015 i686
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably the issue described at http://cweiske.de/tagebuch/pear-php-5.5.htm

Try to fix it with the following:

```
$ pear upgrade -Z Archive_Tar
$ pear install image_graphviz
```

If that does not work, follow the instructions in the blog post.